# How do I generate a HTTP POST request using CURL?

Tags: http, post, curl

I want to generate a HTTP request with CURL:
[image]

and

[image]

Do you guys think this is correct?

`curl --data "GENERATE_SNAPSHOT=Generate Snapshot"  http://170.10.10.20:8888/command`

Answer (score 0):

No, that's a multipart formpost you show but your command line makes a "normal" POST. Something like this line is probably closer:

```
curl -F "GENERATE_SNAPSHOT=Generate Snapshot" http://170.10.10.20:8888/command
```

and I would advice you to use --trace-ascii to study how your request ends up like and compare that you're happy with it. Like this:

```
curl -F "GENERATE_SNAPSHOT=Generate Snapshot" http://170.10.10.20:8888/command --trace-ascii requestlog.txt
```

Comment: I see "GET" communicate to master.css, following the "POST" request. Do you think we need to take care of the "POST"  request as well?

Comment: The GET of the css is what the browser does to render the page containing the form. The POST is the submission of the form data.